# Python: Track latest message sequence ID without gaps

Tags: python, algorithm, networking

I'm writing a networking app in Python that receives numbered messages from a server. The messages have sequence numbers in the range `1..N` and may come out of order. I want to track the latest message received conditioned on there being no gaps in the messages so far.

So for instance,

- if the messages were `1,3,2` I would mark `3` as the latest ungapped message received.
- If the messages were `1,2,5,4` I would mark `2` as the latest ungapped message received since I haven't yet received `3`.
- Once `3` comes in, I would mark `5` as the latest message received.

What's the most efficient way to do this? Is there some data structure or programming idiom that implements an algorithm to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you not just rely on the TCP protocol for reliable and ordered delivery of packets?

Comment: No because they are coming in from multiple sources, each of which deals with a set of messages

Comment: How about walking through them in pairs, and when the absolute difference is > 1, take the lower operand as your latest packet.

Answer (score 0):

I looked around a bit and didn't find a great answer immediately.

Here's a stab I took at doing this via a small blocking class. This could technically be O(N) for a single handle_new_index, but the average time for the handle_new_index operations should still be guaranteed to be constant.

I don't think time complexity will get much better since you have to do an insert on some kind of data structure no matter what you do.

With billions of requests and a really wide spread the non_contiguous set can have a moderate memory footprint.

```
import random

class gapHandler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.greatest = 0
        self.non_contiguous = set()

    def handle_new_index(self, message_index):
        """
        Called when a new numbered request is sent. Updates the current
        index representing the greatest contiguous request.

        """
        self.non_contiguous.add(message_index)
        if message_index == self.greatest + 1:
            self._update_greatest()

    def _update_greatest(self):
        done_updating = False
        while done_updating is False:
            next_index = self.greatest + 1
            if next_index in self.non_contiguous:
                self.greatest = next_index
                self.non_contiguous.remove(next_index)
            else:
                done_updating = True


def demo_gap_handler():
    """ Runs the gapHandler class through a mock trial. """
    gh = gapHandler()

    for block_id in range(20000):
        start = block_id*500 + 1
        end = (block_id + 1)*500 + 1

        indices = [x for x in range(start, end)]
        random.shuffle(indices)
        while indices:
            new_index = indices.pop()
            gh.handle_new_index(new_index)
            if new_index % 50 == 0:
                print(gh.greatest)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    demo_gap_handler()
```

Here's some basic tests:

```
import unittest
import gaps


class testGaps(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_update_greatest(self):
        gh = gaps.gapHandler()
        gh.non_contiguous = set((2, 3, 4, 6))

        gh._update_greatest()
        self.assertEqual(gh.greatest, 0)

        gh.greatest = 1
        gh._update_greatest()
        self.assertEqual(gh.greatest, 4)

    def test_handle_new_index(self):
        gh = gaps.gapHandler()
        gh.non_contiguous = set((2, 3, 4, 6, 2000))

        gh.handle_new_index(7)
        self.assertEqual(gh.greatest, 0)

        gh.handle_new_index(1)
        self.assertEqual(gh.greatest, 4)

        gh.handle_new_index(5)
        self.assertEqual(gh.greatest, 7)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```